# How to use SAS to substitute one word for another in notepad(txt) file

Tags: sas, stata

In file a.txt containing "abc", I want to replace "abc" with a 20000-length string. I could use Stata command `filefilter` for converting ASCII text or binary patterns in a file to do it. How to do it in SAS?

a.txt contents:

```
   {\rtf1
    {\fonttbl{\f1\fmodern\fcharset134;}}
    {\info}
    \sectd\pgwsxn11907\pghsxn16840\marglsxn1418\margrsxn1418
    \margtsxn1440\margbsxn1440\sectdefaultcl
    \headery851{\header\pard\qr\fs18\par}
    \footery992{\footer\pard\qc\f0\fs18\chpgn\par}
    {\pard\qc\sb30\sa30\fs21 \par
    \trowd\trautofit1\trgaph0\trleft-75\intbl\trqc           
    \clbrdrt\brdrs\brdrw30\clbrdrb\brdrs\brdrw10\clvertalc\cellx6993\clbrdrt
    \brdrs\brdrw30\clbrdrb\brdrs\brdrw10\clvertalc\cellx13986\clbrdrt\brdrs\brdrw30
    \clbrdrb\brdrs\brdrw10\clvertalc\cellx20979
    \qc\fs21 x\cell\qc\fs21 y\cell\qc\fs21 z\cell\row
    \trowd\trautofit1\trgaph0\trleft-75\trqc                  
    \clvertalc\cellx6993\clvertalc\cellx13986
    \clvertalc\cellx20979
    \qc\fs21 a\cell\qc\fs21 b\cell\qc\fs21 abc\cell\row
    \trowd\trautofit1\trgaph0\trleft-75\intbl\trqc   
    \clbrdrb\brdrs\brdrw30\clvertalc\cellx6993\clbrdrb\brdrs\brdrw30
    \clvertalc\cellx13986\clbrdrb\brdrs\brdrw30\clvertalc\cellx20979
    \qc\fs21 d\cell\qc\fs21 e\cell\qc\fs21 f\cell\row
    }}
```

Comment: If you're not otherwise using this in SAS, SAS is a poor tool for this purpose.  What is the scope around this - why do you want to use SAS?  Are you then reading it into a dataset or something else, or is this solely changing a .txt file?

Comment: What operating systems are you using? On a UNIX-based machine, you can call shell commands in SAS like this:  `x perl -pi -w -e 's/SEARCH_FOR/REPLACE_WITH/g;' a.txt`.

Comment: Thank you. Operating system is Windows

Answer (score 0):

There are suggestions for some tools [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60034/how-can-you-find-and-replace-text-in-a-file-using-the-windows-command-line-envir) that will work on Windows.

One you have a tool like FART or sed installed, you can use **x** as prefix in SAS to access the command line like [this](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/hostwin/63285/HTML/default/viewer.htm#exittemp.htm).